# Adding values of duplicate items

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicates

I have a shopping cart, and currently the catalog pages allow a user to add duplicate items as long as the total quantity including what is already in the cart, is under the maximum value. That is not the problem, the problem is when in the shopping cart, a user can change the quantity, and can exceed the max if there are duplicate items.

I want a method that can add the values of the duplicate values on a text changed event.

When I use the method I created for the other pages I run into problems. When adding, it will take the total quantity that is in the shopping cart of an item that has a duplicate in the cart and add it to the new quantity added by the user, which will skew the results.

Here is the method mentioned:

```
public static bool getTotalQty(string sessionID, int ProductID, decimal Qty)
{
    double maxQty = 0;
    double totalQty = 0;
    bool isQtyValid = true;

    List<ShoppingCartDTO> shoppingList = ShoppingCart.Fetch(string.Format("WHERE SessionID='{0}'", sessionID));
    foreach (ShoppingCartDTO temp in shoppingList)
    {
         var qty = shoppingList.Where(item => item.ProductID == ProductID).Sum(item => item.Quantity);
         maxQty = getMax(ProductID);                   

         isQtyValid = maxQty == 0 ? true : CheckMaxQty(totalQty, maxQty);
     }
     if (!isQtyValid)
         break;

    return isQtyValid;
}
```

EDIT: With the new linq added I see my problem is that the sum is of the quantity preexisting in the table, not excluding the value its trying to add to the total quantity. So my question is now, can I manipulate the linq statement to work in the qty_Changed so it is not looking at a table for the values its trying to add.. Since they won't necessarily be up to date as the text boxes would be?

The two calls in this method are just to retrieve the max, and then to compare the max and total that is found.

Not sure if you need it, but here is the text changed event that I have as well:

```
public void qty_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool isQtyValid = true;
  decimal qty = 0.0M;
  int productID = 0;
  int index = 0;

  string sessionID = Session["ID"].ToString();

  for (int x = 0; x < cart.Items.Count; x++)
  {
    RepeaterItem item = cart.Items[x];

    TextBox qtyText = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TxtQty");

    if (qtyText.Text != string.Empty)
    {
      qty = Convert.ToDecimal(qtyText.Text);
      productID = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)item.FindControl("lblProductID")).Text);

      isQtyValid = COMMONACES.GetValues.getTotalQty(sessionID, productID, qty, index);
    }

    ((Label)item.FindControl("lblQtyOverMax")).Visible = !isQtyValid;
    CheckOut.Enabled = isQtyValid;
    lblError.Visible = !isQtyValid;
    lblError.Text = isQtyValid ? string.Empty : "Your quantity for one or more items exceeds the maximum allowed. Please check the total quantity and make the needed adjustments.";

    if (!isQtyValid)
        break;
  }
}
```

Any additional info that will help I can try and add.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and single-stepped where the quantity is computed to make sure that it's giving you the right number? Also, I think you can simplify your logic with something like `var qty = shoppingList.Where(item => item.ProductId == ProductID).Sum(item => item.Quantity);`

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you for that line! It hasn't solved my problem but it sure has made the code easier to follow. I am updating my question with that and more info regarding what I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new logic provided by @JimMischel I found the problem was that I was looking only for the sum of the table, and not for the sum of the live variables.
What I did to solve this was to add in an update call before the call to check to see if the quantity's were over the max. This way the Quantity's in the table stay up to date with what is on the site.